# Grails 3.1 can't add library

Tags: grails, google-geocoder, grails-3.1

I'm trying add a library geocoder-java to find coordinates for an adress.

I tryed like bellow in "build.gradle":

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.code.geocoder-java:geocoder-java:0.16'
    ...
}
```

I did the clean and compile, and the library has been downloaded.

But the result was "Cannot resolve symbol" when I try to use the classes.

Comment: I got the same trouble with IntelIj. I don't really know how to solve it, but with some clean / build with gradle, **and a restart of the IDE**, I manage to use the new dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the IntelliJ.

To solve the problem: View > Tool Windows > Gradle > Click the refresh button

Reference:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html